# Error installing watchman on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, make

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman/
git checkout v4.7.0
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libtool libssl-dev
./autogen.sh 
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

At the `make` step, I am getting the following error, which I assume means I cannot proceed with `sudo make install`.

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jcovingt/watchman'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'thirdparty/tap.cpp', needed by 
'thirdparty/libtap_a-tap.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jcovingt/watchman'
Makefile:869: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Go to that folder and make sure this `tap.cpp` exist!

Comment: Of course! :-/ And...it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, I just deleted the folder, re-cloned, and it worked just fine. I think I was running into issues trying to install v4.9.0. Installing at v4.7.0 seems ok.

Comment: For Ubuntu 17.10, also had to `sudo apt-get install pkg-config`, and use the aforementioned `v4.9.0`.

Answer (score 0):

User wez wrote on git about old version problem:

> Sounds like you had previously built an old version in that clone of
>   the repo. You can resolve this by running git clean -dfx to nuke all
>   generated state, then re-run the installation instructions.

Take a look on:>
https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/542