# How to install watchman on Ubuntu 18.04, for react-native? error in make command

Tags: software-installation, make, nodejs, ubuntu-make

I have read this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964364/error-installing-watchman-on-ubuntu-16-04)
.

I wanted nodeman as dependency for react-native

no error upto  `./configure` command and it works fine as given solution

```
gd@gd10:/tmp$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
Cloning into 'watchman'...
remote: Counting objects: 18852, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (103/103), done.
remote: Total 18852 (delta 50), reused 64 (delta 27), pack-reused 18718
Receiving objects: 100% (18852/18852), 12.37 MiB | 1011.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12582/12582), done.
gd@gd10:/tmp$ cd watchman/
gd@gd10:/tmp/watchman$ git checkout v4.7.0
Note: checking out 'v4.7.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 93b67583 watchman: fixup recent test tweaks for windows
gd@gd10:/tmp/watchman$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libtool libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
autoconf is already the newest version (2.69-11).
automake is already the newest version (1:1.15.1-3ubuntu2).
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.0g-2ubuntu4).
libtool is already the newest version (2.4.6-2).
python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
gd@gd10:/tmp/watchman$ ./autogen.sh
configure.ac:21: installing './compile'
configure.ac:2: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:2: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:3: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:3: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
parallel-tests: installing './test-driver'
gd@gd10:/tmp/watchman$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for inline... inline
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for arc... no
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for pcre-config... false
checking for PCRE using false... failed
checking for library containing pthread_create... -lpthread
checking for library containing socket... none required
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking port.h usability... no
checking port.h presence... no
checking for port.h... no
checking sys/inotify.h usability... yes
checking sys/inotify.h presence... yes
checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
checking sys/event.h usability... no
checking sys/event.h presence... no
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking sys/ucred.h usability... no
checking sys/ucred.h presence... no
checking for sys/ucred.h... no
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for mkostemp... yes
checking for kqueue... no
checking for port_create... no
checking for inotify_init... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for statfs... yes
checking for accept4... yes
checking for inotify_init1... yes
checking for getattrlistbulk... no
checking for openat... yes
checking for fdopendir... yes
checking for sys/vfs.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking for sys/statfs.h... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking valgrind/valgrind.h usability... no
checking valgrind/valgrind.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/valgrind.h... no
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking CoreServices/CoreServices.h usability... no
checking CoreServices/CoreServices.h presence... no
checking for CoreServices/CoreServices.h... no
checking for FSEventStreamSetExclusionPaths... no
checking for backtrace... yes
checking for backtrace_symbols... yes
checking for backtrace_symbols_fd... yes
checking for sys_siglist... yes
checking for memmem... yes
checking for struct statvfs.f_fstypename... no
checking for struct statvfs.f_basetype... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating thirdparty/jansson/jansson_config.h
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands

Your build configuration:

        CPPFLAGS =  -D_REENTRANT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
        CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -gdwarf-2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
        LDFLAGS =
        prefix: /usr/local
        version: 4.7.0
        state directory: /usr/local/var/run/watchman
```

but error started after `make` command.

```
gd@gd10:/tmp/watchman$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/watchman'
  CC       thirdparty/libart/src/art.o
  AR       libart.a
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       thirdparty/libtap_a-tap.o
  AR       libtap.a
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       thirdparty/wildmatch/wildmatch.o
  AR       libwildmatch.a
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-dump.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-error.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-hashtable.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-load.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-memory.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-pack_unpack.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-strbuffer.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-strconv.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-utf.o
  CC       thirdparty/jansson/libwmanjson_a-value.o
  AR       libwmanjson.a
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       watchman-argv.o
  CC       watchman-envp.o
  CC       watchman-spawn.o
  CC       watchman-opt.o
  CC       watchman-cfg.o
  CC       watchman-clockspec.o
  CC       watchman-checksock.o
  CC       watchman-fstype.o
  CC       watchman-log.o
  CC       watchman-ignore.o
  CC       watchman-json.o
  CC       watchman-bser.o
  CC       watchman-expflags.o
  CC       watchman-hash.o
hash.c: In function ‘w_hash_bytes’:
hash.c:228:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 12: c+=((uint32_t)k[11])<<24;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash.c:229:7: note: here
       case 11: c+=((uint32_t)k[10])<<16;
       ^~~~
hash.c:229:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 11: c+=((uint32_t)k[10])<<16;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash.c:230:7: note: here
       case 10: c+=((uint32_t)k[9])<<8;
       ^~~~
hash.c:230:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 10: c+=((uint32_t)k[9])<<8;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash.c:231:7: note: here
       case 9 : c+=k[8];
       ^~~~
hash.c:231:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 9 : c+=k[8];
                ~^~~~~~
hash.c:232:7: note: here
       case 8 : b+=((uint32_t)k[7])<<24;
       ^~~~
hash.c:232:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 8 : b+=((uint32_t)k[7])<<24;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash.c:233:7: note: here
       case 7 : b+=((uint32_t)k[6])<<16;
       ^~~~
hash.c:233:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 7 : b+=((uint32_t)k[6])<<16;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash.c:234:7: note: here
       case 6 : b+=((uint32_t)k[5])<<8;
       ^~~~
hash.c:234:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 6 : b+=((uint32_t)k[5])<<8;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash.c:235:7: note: here
       case 5 : b+=k[4];
       ^~~~
hash.c:235:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 5 : b+=k[4];
                ~^~~~~~
hash.c:236:7: note: here
       case 4 : a+=((uint32_t)k[3])<<24;
       ^~~~
hash.c:236:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 4 : a+=((uint32_t)k[3])<<24;
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash.c:237:7: note: here
       case 3 : a+=((uint32_t)k[2])<<16;
       ^~~~
hash.c:237:17: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
       case 3 : a+=((uint32_t)k[2])<<16;
```

according to its solution, I deleted directory but it gave same errors.

Comment: this might be late  but sudo apt-get -y install watchman really save my day

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ref. https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-from-source

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman/
git checkout v4.9.0
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libssl-dev libtool
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Make sure to run  `git checkout v4.9.0`. That is, check out `v4.9.0`, *not* `v4.7`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Users can also avoid downloading the entire repository if they instead run: `curl -L https://github.com/facebook/watchman/archive/v4.9.0.tar.gz | tar xzf -` then `cd watchman-4.9.0`.

Comment: for me, there was one more thing missing. the autogen.sh was not able to generate `configure` to fix that use `sudo apt install pkg-config`

Comment: thanks @Mehari your solution fixed my problem

Comment: If you are under Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.04, try to run `./configure --without-python  --without-pcre --enable-lenient` before `make`

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04, the make will fail with `‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘struct watchman::FileInformation’;` unless you follow @Leo's advise above. Ubuntu 19 uses GCC 8.* and will be more strict with the compile than previous versions.

Comment: I get below error when running `./autogen.sh`
> your system lacks libtoolize

Answer (score 9):

Watchman is available in Debian sid and Ubuntu 20.04 and can be installed with:

```
# apt-get install watchman
```

Comment: Wrong or incomplete information.

Comment: Probably in The Focal Fossa, see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/watchman

Answer (score 3):

Watchman version 4.7.0 isn't compatible with GCC 7.x, as reported here:
https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/467

Note, Ubuntu 18.04 ships with GCC 7.3.

Try building the latest version, v4.9.0, in which the issue is fixed:
https://github.com/facebook/watchman/releases/tag/v4.9.0

Alternatively, use an earlier GCC version for building Watchman, such as 5.4.

Comment: Valiano, I tried both versions but same error occurs after `make `command

Comment: according to old solution, I am just checking out v4.7.0 but actually in `git clone` v4.9 is copied.  I also went to `github repo` of watchman and `releases v4.7.0` but it gave same error.

Comment: @ganesh10, note these lines in output:
`gd@gd10:/tmp/watchman$ git checkout v4.7.0`
`Note: checking out 'v4.7.0'.`

Comment: v4.9.0 worked. instead of `git checkout v4.7.0`, as you said I did `git checkout v4.9. and it solved error in 3 minutes, and I was solving from 2 days.

Comment: @ganesh10 glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Follow all these steps

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman/
```

use this command to check you are in branch or master
    git branch 
if the console print like below output skip this commmand `git checkout v4.9.0`

```
* (HEAD detached at v4.9.0)
  master
```

if you are in master the console print like this

```
* master
```

After this process use all these commands

```
git checkout v4.9.0 // use v4.9.0
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libssl-dev libtool
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install //root user
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04
from @anuradha-weeraman - https://askubuntu.com/a/1205558/

`sudo apt install watchman`

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1205558/

Comment: @karel I know it is a duplicate , that's  why i mentioned from where i got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While following accepted answer, I had been getting error

> Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 42266 (apt)
> N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.

The warning was strong, So I tried following the comment by @Brandon Rhodes and succeeded with following set of instructions

```
curl -L https://github.com/facebook/watchman/archive/v4.9.0.tar.gz | tar xzf -

cd watchman-4.9.0/
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libssl-dev libtool
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

While following accepted answer on Ubuntu(18.04 & 20.04), I experienced the following error:

```
scm/Mercurial.cpp: In constructor ‘watchman::Mercurial::infoCache::infoCache(std::string)’:
scm/Mercurial.cpp:16:40: error: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘struct watchman::FileInformation’; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Werror=class-memaccess]
16 |   memset(&dirstate, 0, sizeof(dirstate));
```

After some investigation I was able to fix this issue by passing **--enable-lenient** to **./configure** to disable promoting warnings to errors.

The complete modified instructions is provided below:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git

cd watchman/

git checkout v4.9.0

sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libssl-dev libtool

./autogen.sh

./configure --without-python  --without-pcre --enable-lenient   

make

sudo make install
```